# Super-fast rounding function (PBC)

Tags: c, performance, floating-point, modeling

I really need very fast round() function in C - 
it is necessary for Monte Carlo particle modeling:
at every step you need to wrap coordinates into periodic box to compute volume interactions : for example

```
for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
    coor.x[i] = a.XReal.x[i]-b.XReal.x[i];
    coor.x[i] = coor.x[i] - SIZE[i]*round(coor.x[i]/SIZE[i]); //PBC
}
```

I've come across some asm hacking with it, but i don't understand asm at all:)
something like this

```
inline int float2int2(float flt)
{
  int intgr;

  __asm__ __volatile__ ("fld %1; fistp %0;" : "=m" (intgr) : "m" (flt));

  return intgr;
}
```

With  fixed boundaries, without round() it works faster.
So, maybe someone knows a better way?..

Comment: The asm you've found is all but useless: It's architecture specific (x86) and uses the old x87 fpu (slow, horrible). If you're on x86-64, you're much better of with sse-instructions, which any sane compiler will automatically emit.

Comment: thanks! I forgot to mention - nearest-int rounding is needed. like 0.8 -> 1, -2.7 -> -3

Comment: Have you tried how the standard function (`remainder()`) that does this compares performance-wise?

Comment: `round()` rounds "to nearest, ties away from zero", the likely faster `rint()` rounds "to nearest, ties to even". If you can tolerate the difference, try `rint()`. Performance wise I would be more concerned about the floating-point division in this code. What are typical values of SIZE[i], and are these compile-time constants?

Comment: This question has a very useful hack that works on a limited range of inputs:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035464/a-fast-method-to-round-a-double-to-a-32-bit-int-explained

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can get some gains by using the right compiler options. With GCC and a modern Intel CPU for example, you should try:

```
-march=nehalem -fno-trapping-math
```

Then the problem with `round` is that it uses a specific rounding mode, which is slow on most platforms. `nearbyint` (or `rint`) should always be faster:

```
coor.x[i] = coor.x[i] - SIZE[i] * nearbyint(coor.x[i] / SIZE[i])
```

Have a look a the [generated assembly](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g492,options:'-O2+-march%3Dnehalem+-fno-trapping-math',source:'%23include+%3Cmath.h%3E%0A%0Adouble+test_nearbyint(double+d)+%7B%0A++return+nearbyint(d)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adouble+test_round(double+d)+%7B%0A++return+round(d)%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

You should also think about vectorizing your code.

Comment: Wouldn't `-ffast-math` be a better choice?  It includes `-funsafe-math-optimizations` as well as a few other options.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd `-ffast-math` doesn't make rounding any faster. Actually, it's enough to use `-fno-trapping-math` to make GCC generate `roundsd` instructions. I edited my answer.

Comment: Also, clang emits `roundsd` for `nearbyint` even without `-fno-trapping-math`. This seems to be correct since `nearbyint` doesn't raise floating point exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking for just fast rounding, ideally you want the whole process of range-reduction into the periodic box to be fast.  As @EOF accurately pointed out in a comment, you could use a C99 standard function like `remainderf()` or `fmodf()`.

```
coor.x[i] -= SIZE[i]*round(coor.x[i]/SIZE[i]);
// same as
coor.x[i] = remainderf(coor.x[i], SIZE[i]);
```

[`fmodf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmod.3.html) rounds towards zero, [`remainderf(3)` rounds towards nearest](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remainder.3.html).

> The `remainder()` function computes the remainder of dividing `x` by `y`.  The return value is `x-n*y`, where `n` is the value `x / y`, rounded
>   to the nearest integer.  If the absolute value of `x-n*y` is 0.5, n is chosen to be even.

Compilers / libraries have several different strategies for implementing these.  With `-ffast-math`, gcc 5.3 for x86-64 inlines a `remainder(x,y)` implementation that transfers the values from SSE registers to x87 registers, and runs `FPREM1` (partial remainder) in a loop until it sets a flag indicating that the result is correct.  (One execution of `FPREM1` can reduce the exponent by at most 63).

clang always emits a call to the library function, either the normal `remainder` entry point, or `__remainder_finite` with `-ffast-math`.

The GNU libm definition uses mostly integer operations, AFAICT from the disassembly [and the C source](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_remainder.c).  On a recent Intel CPU with fast hardware divide, it might be slower than your div, round, mul version.

---

### So you have three options:

- div, round, mul, sub, with fast rounding (use `nearbyint()`, it apparently has the least ugly semantics so it can inline to `roundsd` / `roundss` most easily).  **This way can vectorize, and do all three coordinates at once**.  May need to do it manually, to find something that won't fault for the 4th element.  On Intel Haswell with 128b vectors: 5 uops.  single-precision: `divps`(10-13c latency, one per 7c throughput), `roundps`(2 uops, 6c latency, one per 2c throughput), `mulps`(5c latency, one per 0.5c throughput), `subps`(3c latency, one per 1c throughput).  Some of these compete with each other for execution ports.  **Total latency: 27c**.  Probable throughput, maybe something like **one per 7c** (totally bottlenecked by divps)
- gcc's inlined x87 `FPREM1`.  (probably only needs to run one iteration, so on Haswell: 41 uops, 27c latency, one per 17c throughput, plus some overhead for getting data between xmm and x87 regs.  Can't vectorize.
- glibc's mostly-integer implementation: no idea, probably worse than either of the other two, on modern x86 CPUs.  But, **[probably significantly higher accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505513/floating-point-modulo-operation#comment12038890_9505761)** than the manual div/round/mul/sub.

---

Bottom line, if this is a speed issue, you should **definitely look into vectorizing with SSE/AVX to do all three coordinates of a point in one vector**.  Or, a coordinate of four points at once, or whatever is convenient.  Ideally you can make use of all 4 (or 8 with AVX) single-precision elements of the vector ALUs.  (or 2 / 4 for double-precision).

Even scalar, I think your current code with `nearbyint()` is going to be the fastest choice, but you can easily go three times faster than that with vectors.