# Efficient wrap around of doubles in C on unit axis

Tags: c, double

Consider an axis like so:

[image: boundary]

Now consider an atom placed on the axis at position: `double pos;` with `0.0 < pos < 1.0`. The position may be displaced by `double dt;` which can be any (+ve/-ve) double thus `double newPos = pos + dt;` could possibly not lie within the range `0.0 < newPos < 1.0`.

Is there any way to implement a wrap around eg. if atom leaves on the right side re-insert on the left without resulting to `fmod` (which may be too slow for my case)?

I have a feeling there should be a straight-forward way since when `dt` is an integer (in the sense that there is no fractional part) the position remains unchanged (with wraparound) ie. adding `0.2 + 1.0` is still `0.2` (or `2.0,3.0...`) and I can extract the fractional part quickly enough using `double frac = myDouble - ((long) myDouble);` but anything I try doesn't really work on all cases.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: If you're storing values in floating point format then you must accept and handle rounding errors.

Comment: Sounds like `ouble frac = myDouble - ((long)myDouble)` is good enough not only for integers, but also for all other values. What do you expect from `0.2+1.4`, for example? Is it `0.6`?

Comment: @barakmanos `0.2 + 1.0=0.2` then `0.2+0.4=0.6` so `0.6`

Comment: I rest my case then, you just need to treat negative value in a slightly different way, that's all.

Comment: @2501 `pos` and `dt` will 99% of the time be of similar magnitude so the floating point error should be acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
newPos = pos + dt;
if (newPos == (long)newPos)
    newPos = 0;
else if (newPos > 0)
    newPos -= (long)newPos;
else
    newPos -= (long)newPos-1;
```

Or alternatively:

```
newPos = pos + dt;
newPos -= (long)newPos;
if (newPos < 0)
    newPos += 1;
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. I'll give it a few tries in a real scenario and let you know

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs: No problem. Allow me to change the `>= 0` to `> 0` (though it won't make much of a difference).

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs: And please see an alternative solution added to the answer.

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs: In addition, in order to ensure consistency across different platforms, I would recommend to use `long long` instead of `long`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't muddle with conversions to integers and possible undefined behavior. Rather use the completely portable floating point version of remainder:

```
const double raw = pos + dt;
const double wrap = raw >= 1.0 ? fmod( raw , 1.0 ) : raw;
```

Since you mentioned that the results rarely exceeds 1.0, this function shouldn't cause any performance problems. Even if it does, the implementation of fmod [is fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9505761/4082723). It should also be as accurate as possible.